# When is the best time to check in for ryanair to get window or aisle seats?

Tags: seating, ryanair

Ryanair lets you check in 2 days before the flight. Then it gives you some seats. Are those random or do they save the window and aisle seats in case someone buys them? My strategy is to leave it until the latest possible time but I had mixed results.

When should I check in to maximise my chances of getting a window or aisle seat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can never know for sure. It is random allocation. They usually allocate the middle seats first. I recommend doing it a few hours before the flight. Especially with a mobile boarding pass you will be fine.

Most of the middle seats will be gone, so you will have a better chance of either a window or aisle seat, or a luxury seat with extra legroom. This has worked for me before.

From [this guide](https://whereistara.com/secret-tips-for-flying-ryanair/):

> My recommended Ryanair check in time is 2 hours before your flight if you're non-EU/EEA. If you're EU and have your boarding pass, then 1.5 hrs SHOULD be fine if it's not high season and a busy airport.